# Position of list inside a nested list changes upon sorting

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, nested-lists

I have a nested list of 4 lists inside.

```
ListOflist has: list[0] contains Id
                list[1] contains power values
                list[2] contains count values.
```

I'm trying this function to sort the list in an ascending order:

```
bool ascending = true; // ascending
int mult = ascending ? 1 : -1;
listoflist.Sort((a, b) => mult * a[2].CompareTo(b[2]));
```

The goal is to arrange the list of lists according to count values, which mean the field two.
When I try to display the list of lists after sorting, list[0] doesn't contain the Ids but the different values instead and the order of the lists inside the nested list has changed.

Do you have any idea what the error I've made could be?

Comment: Why you use a `List<int>` for properties? Use a class with properties `Id`, `Power`, `Count` properties and store instances in a `List<ClassName>`

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you provide a sample with a desired result? I think you don't want to sort but create different lists.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're actually the values and not an object - try using a custom object:

```
 class Data
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public long Power { get; set; }
            public int Count { get; set; }
        }

        var listoflist = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data {Id = "#1", Power = 2, Count = 10},
            new Data {Id = "#2", Power = 3, Count = 2},
            new Data {Id = "#3", Power = 4, Count = 5}
        };

        var ascending = true; // ascending
        var mult = ascending ? 1 : -1;

        listoflist.Sort((a, b) => mult * a.Count.CompareTo(b.Count));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use list of lists instead of list of objects, but in you situation you could use LINQ (although it adds an extra instance of List<> in memory)

```
   bool ascending = true;
   if (ascending)
       listoflist= listoflist.OrderBy(l => l[2]).ToList();
   else
       listoflist = listoflist.OrderByDescending(l => l[2]).ToList();
```